# Bigram detection: Comparing a string with a list in order to merge certain substrings

Tags: python, string, list, substring

Considering I have a string:

```
text = "You are good at data mining and machine learning"
```

and also a list of possible bigrams:

```
bigrams = ["data mining", "machine learning"]
```

How could I detect those bigrams in the text and merge the two words together, so that my result would be a string like:

```
new_text = "You are good at data_mining and machine_learning"
```

I need to apply this to a much bigger string (corpus) and a longer list of bigrams.

I tried it with string.replace() in:

```
new_text = [x.replace(" ","_") for x in text if x in bigrams]
```

But this results in an empty list.

Comment: not the most efficient i think but `for bigram in bigrams: text = text.replace(bigram,bigram.replace(' ','_'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `re` and calls replace to turn spaces into underscores on only the matching grams.

```
>>> import re
>>> bigrams = ["data mining", "machine learning"]
>>> text = "You are good at data mining and machine learning"
>>> re.sub('('+'|'.join('\\b'+re.escape(g)+'\\b' for g in bigrams)+')', 
...        lambda m: m.group(0).replace(' ', '_'), text)
'You are good at data_mining and machine_learning'
```

Ideally, this is the most efficient solution, because finding the non-overlapping occurrences of a set of strings in a string can be done in time mostly determined by the length of the string and not the size of the set of strings, once that set is prefix indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the elegant way like for example:

```
input_list = text.split(" ")

def ngrams(input_list, n):
  return zip(*[input_list[i:] for i in range(n)])
```

where n should be 2 in your case. This returns a list of tuples containing all bigram combinations. Afterwards you could simply use a list comprehension to concat each tuple again

```
list_of_bigrams = [bigram[0] + "_" + bigram[1] for bigram in ngrams(input_list,2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this:

```
for bigram in bigrams:
    text = text.replace(bigram, "_".join(split(bigram)))
```

or as Chris noted

```
for bigram in bigrams:
    text = text.replace(bigram, bigram.replace(" ", "_"))
```

I'm not sure which is faster.